# Epoll reverse proxy stuck while writing client

Tags: c++, c, sockets, reverse-proxy, epoll

I am trying to write reverse proxy with nonblocking socket and epoll. That seems ok at first, but when I tried to open a big jpg file, I got stuck. 
When I try to write into client sometimes It may not writable and how can I handle proper way.

Additional Notes:

```
this->getFd() = ProxyFd
this->clientHandler->getFd = clientFd
```

I am using `EPOLLET` flag both proxy and client

```
   if( (flag & EPOLLIN) ){
        char buffer[1025] = {'\0'};
        int readSize;
        while( (readSize = read(this->getFd(),buffer,1024)) > 0){
            this->headerParse(buffer);
            this->readSize += readSize;
            int check = 0;
            do{
                check = write(this->clientHandler->getFd(),buffer,readSize);
            }while(check < 0);

        }
        if(this->headerEnd == 1 && this->readSize >= this->headerLenght  ){
            close(this->clientHandler->getFd());
            close(this->getFd());
            delete this->clientHandler;
            delete this;
        } 
    }
```

Thanks for taking time to read.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your headerParse() method doesn't change buffer in a size-extending way (you'd need to update readsize, at least, not to mention the buffer full scenario), it seems like your write() path is broken.

if the socket you're writing to is also in nonblocking mode, it's perfectly legal for write() to return -1 (and set errno to EGAIN or EWOULDBLOCK or whatever your platform has) before you wrote all data. 
In that case, you must store the remaining data (the remainder of buffer minus what was written if one or more calls to write() succeeded), program epoll to notify the clientHandler->getFd() descriptor for writeability, if not already, and when you get subsequent "write ready" event, you write the data you stored. On this case, the write() can again be unable to flush all your data, so you must cycle until all data is sent.